# Manage POST time output in PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, forms, time, http-post

Working on a smart **time manager**, informations sent through a form, I would like to transform a form time output, captured with :

```
public function getFormOutput(Request $request) 
{
    $request->except('_token');
    $startTimeInput = $request->input('starttime');
    $endTimeInput = $request->input('endtime');
    $breakTimeInput = $request->input('breaktime');
}
```

Here there is no problem, the values are formated like **"xx:xx"**

---

**I'm now trying to calculate the time difference between startTime  and endTime.**

Using the `strtotime()` as that does not work :

```
$startTime = strtotime($startTimeInput);
$endTime = strtotime($endTimeInput);
```

They both took the value :

```
1552550400
```

Which seems to be time of 1 January 1970 in milliseconds.

---

Here is my **timeManager.blade.php** view :

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'agenda']) !!}
      {!! Form::label('starttime', 'Heure de début: ') !!}
      {!! Form::input('time', 'starttime') !!}
      <tr>
      {!! Form::label('endtime', 'Heure de fin: ') !!}
      {!! Form::input('time', 'endtime') !!}
      <tr>
      {!! Form::label('breaktime', 'Temps de pause: ') !!}
      {!! Form::input('time', 'breaktime') !!}
      <tr>
      {!! Form::submit('Envoyer' ) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**My question is : how to calculate the difference between start time et end time ?**

Comment: what is your question?? Please specify the expected output you want

Comment: The difference between the two times in **minutes or seconds or hours**??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to calculate **difference of time**:

**1st Method:**

```
// calculate the start timestamp
$startdatetime = strtotime($startTimeInput);
// calculate the end timestamp
$enddatetime = strtotime($endTimeInput);
// calulate the difference in seconds
$difference = $enddatetime - $startdatetime;
// hours is the whole number of the division between seconds and SECONDS_PER_HOUR
$hoursDiff = $difference / 3600;
// and the minutes is the remainder
$minutesDiffRemainder = $difference % 3600;
// output the result
echo $hoursDiff . "hours " . $minutesDiffRemainder . "mins";
```

**2nd Method:**

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($startTimeInput);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($endTimeInput);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y years, %M months, %D days, %I minutes, %S seconds');
```

I hope it would helpful.